# How can 8 spaces in php file make apache to crash?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, crash

I working on project, developed with Zend Framework and decided to do some work at home, but i ran in strange problem: when I open home page of that website on my local machine, it closes connetcion immediately and Windows error pops up, saying that apache was crashed (but actually it isn't).

So by switching to another revisions of project I've found that problem occurs, when one of Zend Framework files (actually Zend_Auth class) has 8 spaces of indentation in one of methods (someone of our team modified that file, and then has deleted his changes, leaving spaces there).

Interesting thing: if i delete or add space to line, that makes it happen, website works as normal, if I return those 8 spaces, it would be broken again.

My specs:

Windows 7
Apache 2.2.22 (from www.apachelounge.com) installed as service (running from system user account)
PHP 5.3

EDIT: If someone interesting, those spaces are in file Auth.php (Zend_Auth class) at line 118. You could try it on your projects with your setups.

Comment: if you use 2 or 3 spaces instead of 8, would it crash ?

Comment: Could one of those spaces be some other invisible unicode 'character'?What happens if you erase those 8 spaces and insert 8 'homespun' spaces?

Comment: To HamZa DzCyberDeV:No! I've tried 2,3,7,9 spaces and it works just fine! Only 8 spaces make it happen.

Comment: To jgivoni: I deleted all spaces and inserted 8 normal spaces again - the problem is still there!

Comment: @hjdm how about any other lines? (and please [use the `@name` syntax when replying](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting))

Comment: @AlvinWong I've tried several lines with code and without code in Auth.php - result is the same. However, in other files (index.php, IndexController.php) 8 spaces do nothing. Maybe I need to do some more experiments.

Comment: "saying that apache was crashed (but actually it isn't)" <- Not the whole apache has crashed, but at least a server pool process (perhaps even a CGI process). I'm pretty sure it is not a bug of apache but has something to do with PHP or the apache PHP handler. Could you please tell us the complete/exact PHP version (5.3.X?)

Answer (score 2):

It's a shot in the dark, but then it's a weird problem you've got: Could it be a case of the ["Bush hid the facts"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) surprise? (see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699014/file-output-in-python-giving-me-garbage)). It kind of smells like it since adding or deleting a space makes the problem disappear... and you did say you're running Windows.